# How to get value of Radio Buttons?

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have a group box contains radio buttons
eg.

> **o** Male
>
> **o** Female

i want my code to get the selected value of radio button and copy it to string type variable
kindly use simple code cause m not very professional

thanks

Comment: hey @CodingMash he has referred to as 'ratio button' everywhere am really thinking of any such control !

Comment: Its a type definitely, as she gives example of radio buttons, male female one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**For Win Forms :**

To get the value (assuming that you want the value, not the text) out of a radio button, you get the Checked property:

```
string value = "";
bool isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
if(isChecked )
  value=radioButton1.Text;
else
  value=radioButton2.Text;
```

**For Web Forms :**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoPriceRange" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Male">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Female">Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And CS-in some button click

```
string value=rdoPriceRange.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to check one if you have two

```
if(rbMale.Checked)
{

}
else
{

}
```

You need to check all the checkboxes if more then two

```
if(rb1.Checked)
{

}
else if(rb2.Checked)
{

}
else if(rb3.Checked)
{

}
```

Comment: You need to check both if there's two if you don't have a default property set.

Comment: Bit off topic, but let's program correctly: Why do you check "if (a==true)" isn't it enough for booleans to check "if (a)". Your method seems like "if (a==true) {b=true;} else {b=false;}" while in fact you mean "b = a;"

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a Common Event for your RadioButtons, and you can use the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property to pass information to your string or you can use the Text Property if you want your string to hold the same value as the Text of your RadioButton.

Something like this.

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
        sex = ((RadioButton)sender).Tag.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that using the Common Event described above works well and you could have the common event set up like this:

```
private void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RadioButton r in yourPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (r.Checked)
                textBox.Text = r.Text;
        }
    }
```

Of course, then you can't have other controls in your panel that you use, but it's useful if you just have a separate panel for all your radio buttons (such as using a sub panel inside a group box or however you prefer to organize your controls)

Answer (score 2):

An alterntive is to use an enum and a component class that extends the standard RadioButton.

```
public enum Genders
{
    Male,
    Female
}

[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(RadioButton))]
public partial class GenderRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public GenderRadioButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public GenderRadioButton (IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Genders gender{ get; set; }
}
```

Use a common event handler for the GenderRadioButtons

```
private void Gender_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked)
    {
        //get selected value
        Genders myGender = ((GenderRadioButton)sender).Gender;
        //get the name of the enum value
        string GenderName = Enum.GetName(typeof(Genders ), myGender);
        //do any work required when you change gender
        switch (myGender)
        {
            case Genders.Male:
                break;
            case Genders.Female:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To Get the Value when the radio button is checked**

```
if (rdbtnSN06.IsChecked == true)
{
string RadiobuttonContent =Convert.ToString(rdbtnSN06.Content.ToString());
}
else
{
string RadiobuttonContent =Convert.ToString(rdbtnSN07.Content.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Forms**

For cases where there are multiple radio buttons to check, this function is very compact:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Get the value of the radio button that is checked.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="buttons">The radio buttons to look through</param>
/// <returns>The name of the radio button that is checked</returns>
public static string GetCheckedRadioButton(params RadioButton[] radioButtons)
{
    // Look at each button, returning the text of the one that is checked.
    foreach (RadioButton button in radioButtons)
    {
        if (button.Checked)
            return button.Text;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily like bellow,

```cs
_employee.Gender = rbtnMale.Checked?rbtnMale.Text:_employee.Gender;
_employee.Gender = rbtnFemale.Checked?rbtnFemale.Text:_employee.Gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# WinForm**

```
public string GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(Control parent)
{
    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = parent.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
    if (checkedRadioButton is object)
    {
        return checkedRadioButton.Text;
    }

    return "";
}
```

**Usage**
You can add RadioButtons into GroupBox, Panel or Form then get the checked text by

```
string selectedText1 = GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(GroupBox1);
string selectedText2 = GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(Panel1);
string selectedText3 = GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(Form1);
```

**VB.NET WinForm**

```
Public Function GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(Byval parent As Control) As String
   Dim checkedRadioButton As RadioButton = parent.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked)
   If checkedRadioButton IsNot Nothing Then
      Return checkedRadioButton.Text
   End If
   Return ""
End Function
```

**Usage**
You can add RadioButtons into GroupBox, Panel or Form then get the checked text by

```
Dim selectedText1 As String = GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(GroupBox1)
Dim selectedText2 As String = GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(Panel1)
Dim selectedText3 As String = GetCheckedRadioButtonTextByParent(Form1)
```