# Capture name on a radio button?

Tags: c#, winforms

Being a big *newbie to Coding*, how do I get the following part working?
I want to capture the `Text` of a `RadioButton`.

**For instance**

```
radio1.Text = weekly

radio2.Text = monthly

// Doesn't compile; to show the requirement only
if (radio1.checked) then 3
  write weekly
else if (radio2.checked) then 
  write monthly

// write to txt file 
var line = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
  $"First Name:               {tfirstn.Text}",
  $"Last Name:                {tlastn.Text}",
  $"Address:                  {taddr.Text}",
  $"Mobile Number:            {tmobi.Text}",
  $"Recurring Payment Amount: {rpabox.Text}",
  $"Account Number:           {taccnbr.Text}",
   // this should display "weekly" or "monthly" depending on radio button checked
  $"Frequency:                {}", 
  $"",
  $"",
   ""
);
```

Comment: Is this wpf or winforms?

Comment: hey bro, it's winforms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of Radio Buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539051/how-to-get-value-of-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *all* radiobuttons of interest are in the *same* container, e.g. `myPanel`, you can try *Linq*: among all the `RadioButton`s  which are in the container (`Daily`, `Weekly`, `Monthly`, `Yearly` etc.), let's find out the `First` one which is `Check`ed, and take its `Text` (if all `RadioButton`s are unchecked, return `"???"`)

```
using System.Linq;

...

radio1.Text = "Weekly";
radio2.Text = "Monthly";

...

string frequency = myPanel // put "this" if radiobuttons are on the form
  .Controls
  .OfType<RadioButton>()
  .FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.Checked)
 ?.Text ?? "???"; // "???" - if none radiobutton is checked

...

var line = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
  ...
  $"Frequency:                {frequency}", // this should display Weekly or Monthly  
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
radio1.Checked ? "weekly" : "monthly"
```

upd: to make the answer more clear

```
var line = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
              $"First Name:               {tfirstn.Text}",
              $"Last Name:                {tlastn.Text}",
              $"Address:                  {taddr.Text}",
              $"Mobile Number:            {tmobi.Text}",
              $"Recurring Payment Amount: {rpabox.Text}",
              $"Account Number:           {taccnbr.Text}",
              "Frequency:"              + radio1.Checked ? "weekly" : "monthly",
              $"",
              $"",
               ""
            );
```

This will print "weekly" if radio1 is selected, or "monthly" if radio2 is selected **or no radio is selected**

Comment: what if neither is checked?

Comment: It's unclear from the question, if one of them is checked or not. But only 2 cases were present. Assuming that no check for this provided before in code, the default value is "monthly" for case when no radio is checked, if we use my code above

Comment: by doing that i am getting : missing close delim, unexpected token, syntax error

Comment: edited my answer. seems that string interpolation doesn't take expression that way, but simple concat should work

Comment: still not working, if you had to rewrite the code how would you do it?

Comment: Make the expression without braces, my fault again, forgot to remove them when edited. This should finally work.

Comment: still not bro, only one error though now, textbox does not contain definition for Checked?

Comment: I thought that radio1 and radio2 are RadioButtons (which contain "Checked" property) not TextBox. Then it becomes unclear for me.